# Symfony shows default page also if it doesn't exist anymore

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig

I've installed on my Ubuntu server, Symfony 3.3.6.

The problem is that it shows me the default page, also if I delete all code on "index.html.twig" or if I edit the code with my code. If I add views and Controllers, Symfony doesn't consider them and it shows me a 404 error.

I can't understand why and I don't find any error in config.php or app.php files.

I've also tried to set `auto_reload: true` on my config.yml but it doesn't matter... what I've to do? I'm quiet desperate...

**EDIT:** I've forgotten to say that if I delete index.html.twig, it shows me an error, so I'm not in wrong path

My twig parameters in config.yml

```
twig:
#    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    auto_reload: true
    debug: true
    cache: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to clear the cache

To clear the dev cache do

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

To clear the prod cache do

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

You can also tell twig not to cache like this. Amend your

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
twig:
    cache: false
    debug: true
```

This assumes you are working in the dev environment

If you don't see the debug toolbar at the bottom of your web pages then you are probably working on a prod environment. In that case you may need to move that twig config to your `app/config/config.yml`

Comment: If it works (now I try) how I can make this automatic? I can't clear cache everytime I up an edit

Comment: If you are working on the dev env you dont normally need to, however if you are working on a Prod env, you will need to do this all the time. Are you developing on a PROD environment? If so it would be best not to for this and other good reasons

Comment: I'm working on default environment. On Windows I'v had to do nothing. What I've to set?

Comment: See my second attempt

Comment: Okay, solved thanks! I've had forgotten to switch app.php with app_dev.php . On windows, I'v had not to do this. Do you know why?

Comment: Is your Non Windows System a Hosted site?

Comment: Nope, it's my old pc with ubuntu